# How to find shopify domain from real domain

Tags: javascript, shopify

can any please help me out how to find shopify domain name from real domain.
For instance my store domain name is shoponline.com domain mapped on ilovemystore.myshopify.com.
I know that Shopify.shop command will return shopify store name but how to implement this into javascript.
Already spent more than 48 hours on it but didn't get any clue.
Highly appreciate for fastest reply.
Thanks

Comment: Oh yes, forget to mention this javascript call run from chrome extension.

Comment: For your own store, you can create a Javascript variable based on the `{{ shop.permanent_domain }}` value from Liquid.  For an arbitrary 3rd-party Shopify store you're going to have a bit more trouble...

Comment: @DaveB thanks for prompt reply however javascript i am using its not have Shopify framework i am using into chrome extension which don't have capability to run {{shop.permanent_domain }} to get shopify domain.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking to read the Shopify domain using JavaScript.

Shopify already provide that information in a global object so it's just a case of knowing where to look.

```
console.log( window.Shopify.shop );
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. How can chrome extension access javascript variables

Comment: That seems a little beyond the scope of the original question but for the sake of completeness, use a content script to add your own code to the page which is capable of accessing window.

Comment: Sorry for being dump
Following code return error
`const t=window.Shopify.shop;`

**Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'shop' of undefined**